# Complex and real differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> Let $h=(u,v): \Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ be a $C^1$ function. Then, $f:\Bbb{C} \rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ is an analytic function if it satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equation, where $f=u+iv$.

I have to prove or disprove the above statement. I have tried the following

> As $h$ is $C^1$ then the first order partial derivatives are continuous. So $f$ is an analytic function.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your proof cannot be correct because it does not use the Cauchy-Riemann equations. – What is your definition of “analytic”?

Comment: In the problem it is given that $f$ is satisfying C-R equation.

Comment: Yes, but your proof does not use that fact.

Comment: Okay so if I write $f$ is satisfying C-R equation and the first order partial derivatives of $u,v$ are continuous. Hence $f$ is an analytic

Comment: (1) It is correct (but somewhat trivial) that if $h$ is $C^1$ then $f$ has continuous derivatives of the first order. (2) It is also correct that if  $f$ has continuous derivatives of the first order and these satisfy the CR equations then $f$ is analytic. – My guess is that you are expected to *prove* (2). Your attempt is essentially a reformulation of the statement, not a proof.